# Run Time Error '380' on ListBox [Could not set the Selected property. Invalid property value.]

Tags: excel, listbox, vba

I’ve reviewed 10s of reported problems with similar error code but none match my scenario..
I have a ListBox that I populate using the .List property...  The ListBox behaves as expected except when (in sequence):
1. I filter out non-selected items and reset the .List property with the filtered items (no issues there)
2.  I attempt to “mark” all items as selected (I get the error as soon as I set the .Selected property for the first item).

Here is the code (I’ve tried many different variations, but this is the “cleanest”):

```
Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Range(rngTarget.Cells(2, 1), rngTarget.Cells(rngTarget.Rows.Count, lbSelection.ColumnCount))
lbSelection.Clear
lbSelection.List = rngTarget.Cells.Value
lItemCnt = lbSelection.ListCount - 1
For lItemNdx = 0 To lItemCnt
    lbSelection.Selected(lItemNdx) = True
Next lItemNdx
```

The error occurred on the first encounter of `lbSelection.Selected(lItemNdx) = True`.  All the indices are valid, the dataset/range is valid with all rows/columns having valid data, and there are only 5 columns in the list (i.e., less than the max of 10).  I’ve also tried to first assign the dataset (range) to a variant and then the variant to the .List property, but that didn’t make a difference.  I’ve also tried “unmarking” all items before clearing the list..    What is interesting is that, in the debugger when the error is encountered, the .ListCount property shows the correct number of rows.  HOWEVER, the GUI shows a blank list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S.   Populating the ListBox “manually” using .AddItem method is not a practical option for my purposes (nor using .RowSource property).

Environment:  Excel 2010, standard.  Windows 7 Pro.

Enclosing fuller code for review (data not enclosed but consists of 457 rows [first row is header and not part of the listbox] and 5 columns --all text).  To replicate the issues, simply deselect the  first item in the list.

Button to call userform:

```
`Sub LoadSampleForm()
    frmTestLB.InitControls
End Sub`
```

Userform code:

`    Option Explicit
    Private bIgnorEvents As Boolean

```
Public Sub InitControls()
Dim lItemNdx As Long
Dim lItemCnt As Long
    bIgnorEvents = True
    lbSelection.Clear
    lbSelection.ColumnCount = 5
    lbSelection.ColumnWidths = "45 pt;155 pt;70 pt;70 pt;70 pt"
    lbSelection.List = Worksheets("Sample").Range(Worksheets("Sample").Cells(2, 1), Worksheets("Sample").Cells(457, 5)).Value

    lItemCnt = lbSelection.ListCount - 1
    For lItemNdx = 0 To lItemCnt
        lbSelection.Selected(lItemNdx) = True
    Next lItemNdx
    bIgnorEvents = False
    Me.Show
End Sub

Private Sub lbSelection_Change()
Dim bAppAlert As Boolean
Dim lItemCnt As Long
Dim lItemNdx As Long
Dim lKeyColNdx As Long
Dim rngTarget As Range          'Temporary range for items to be searched
Dim wsTemp As Worksheet         'Temporary worksheet used for target range and applying Lookup function
    If (Not bIgnorEvents) Then
        bIgnorEvents = True

        Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        lKeyColNdx = 1
        lItemCnt = lbSelection.ListCount + 1
        wsTemp.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lItemCnt, lbSelection.ColumnCount)).Value = lbSelection.List
        Set rngTarget = wsTemp.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lItemCnt, lbSelection.ColumnCount + 1))
        rngTarget.Cells(1, lbSelection.ColumnCount + 1).Value = "Selected"

        For lItemNdx = 2 To lItemCnt
            If (lbSelection.Selected(lItemNdx - 2)) Then
                rngTarget.Cells(lItemNdx, lbSelection.ColumnCount + 1).Value = 1
            Else
                rngTarget.Cells(lItemNdx, lbSelection.ColumnCount + 1).Value = 0
            End If
        Next lItemNdx

        rngTarget.AutoFilter Field:=lbSelection.ColumnCount + 1, Criteria1:="=0"
        rngTarget.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        wsTemp.AutoFilterMode = False

        Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Range(rngTarget.Cells(2, 1), rngTarget.Cells(rngTarget.Rows.Count, lbSelection.ColumnCount))
        lbSelection.Clear
        lbSelection.List = rngTarget.Cells.Value

        lItemCnt = lbSelection.ListCount - 1
        For lItemNdx = 0 To lItemCnt
            lbSelection.Selected(lItemNdx) = True
        Next lItemNdx

        'Clean-up:  Remove temp sheet without prompts
        bAppAlert = Application.DisplayAlerts   'Current setting
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False       'Supress DisplayAlerts
        wsTemp.Delete                           'Delete temp sheet
        Application.DisplayAlerts = bAppAlert   'Restore original DisplayAlerts setting
        Set rngTarget = Nothing
        Set wsTemp = Nothing

        bIgnorEvents = False
    End If
End Sub`
```

Comment: What does the range look like, if it an export from another source is it possible there are any 'Null' values or other values that Excel/VBA won't natively recognise? It seems most likely it is falling down on the values that it is trying to populate the listbox with as you say the GUI appears blank but the listcount property is working.

Comment: Also, can you tell us the value of lItemNdx, lbSelection.ListCount, and lbSelection.list(lItemNdx) when you debug it?

Comment: Dave,

Thanks for taking interest (and sorry for the delayed response as I was monitoring another thread and missed yours..) The range consists of 5 columns and 456 rows.
Here are some details for you from the debugger, just right I enter the loop and before the first iteration of ` lbSelection.Selected(lItemNdx) = True `:

`?rngTarget.Address $A$2:$E$457 
?lItemNdx  0  
?lItemCnt 455 
?lbSelection.ListCount  456 
?lbSelection.ColumnCount  5  
?lbSelection.ColumnWidths 45 pt;155 pt;70 pt;70 pt;70 pt `
?lbSelection.list(lItemNdx) c

Comment: Looks like the issue is that you have put code changing the ListBox in the ListBox_Change event. Unfortunately, it looks like the ListBox object is not covered by the Application.EnableEvents property so changing it to false doesn't help. If you put your code into a command button it should work.

Comment: Dave, you are correct.  The issue is with the Change event --if I move the code out and manually (i.e., say through a Command Button) the code runs fine.  BUT, I do need to execute that code upon Change (e.g., user deselecting and item).  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, I think you need to rethink your approach. You won't be able to rebuild the list in the Listbox as part of the Listbox_Change event so you'll need to find another way around it. Is there a specific reason you can't use the Listbox.Rowsource property? There might be ways around that.

Comment: The ListBox is part of a more complex user form that filters, sort and removes items from the listbox without permanently altering the source.  The source could include thousands of rows.  To use the .Rowsource property I have to copy (and recopy) the source to another sheet.  This could be costly and messy.

Comment: You could make a complete copy of the raw data just once in the initialize event of the userform and set the range address of the copy as the rowsource for your listbox, then you can manipulate that range as appropriate for your purposes.

Comment: So, I've spend the last few days refactoring everything to support the the use of the .RowSource property but ran into a major limitation:  .RowSource can't handle a non-contiguous range (As a result of a filter operation).  I guess I can copy the that range into yet another sheet and make it contiguous and point the .RowSource to it, but then I have to constantly jump back and forth between sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

```
lbSelection.List = rngTarget.Cells.Value
```

To:

```
lbSelection.List = rngTarget
```

Comment: jbarker2160,
Thanks very much for responding..   Unfortunately, the suggested fix caused “Could not set the list property.   Invalid property array index” error.   I also tried using  `lbSelection.List = rngTarget.Value`, but that produced my original error.

Comment: Are you trying to use a range that has a different number of columns than the ListBox? ANd also, why is the RowSource property not applicable?

Comment: Yes, I am.  I had concerns there too so, to be sure, the code uses the ListBox number of columns (before I clear it) to set the range:

`Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Range(rngTarget.Cells(2, 1), rngTarget.Cells(rngTarget.Rows.Count, lbSelection.ColumnCount))`
The range is columns are 1 though `lbSelection.ColumnCount` (which is actually 5).

Comment: Ok.  I think you are selecting the second row and first column of your range and not of the worksheet so I think you're only picking up the first column and it's probably hidden with a width of 0, right?  It would be helpful to have your workbook.  There are so many variables that could affect this.

Comment: Just clarifying my last comment... Yes, I am USING THE CORRECT NUMBER OF COLUMNS... I had concerns there too so, to be sure, the code uses the ListBox number of columns (before I clear it) to set the range: Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Range(rngTarget.Cells(2, 1), rngTarget.Cells(rngTarget.Rows.Count, lbSelection.ColumnCount)) The range is columns are 1 though lbSelection.ColumnCount (which is actually 5).

Comment: jbarker2160,
The reason I start on row 2 is that the first row contain headers, so that data starts on the second row.  In the debugger (after the .List property assignment), I get the following:
‘?lbSelection.ColumnCount
 5 
?lbSelection.ColumnWidths
45 pt;155 pt;70 pt;70 pt;70 pt
?lbSelection.ListCount
 456`

And those numbers match my data set/specs.

Comment: Can you post a link to your workbook.  There are about 15 things that I'd need to check

Comment: I am embarrassed to ask but how to I post my file?  Can I do it in the main area so others can see it?  Thanks.